# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n^{10}+4n^5+1)/(4n^{15}+4n^{12}+5)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Test whether the following series converges:
>   
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2\cdot n^{10}+4\cdot n^5+1}{4\cdot n^{15}+4\cdot n^{12}+5}$$

$1.$ I know that it does not make sense to use the root test or the ration test, but algebraic I can not see why the result will be $1$

$2.$ using the limit comparison test shouldn't I use $\;\;\dfrac{1}{n^{15}}$?

Comment: @Timbuc Sorry, edited

Comment: I would compare to $\frac{1}{n^{5}}$

Comment: If you look only at the dominant terms of numerator and denominator, what do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{2n^{10}+4 n^5+1}{4n^{15}+4n^{12}+5}\le\frac{7n^{10}}{4n^{15}}=\frac74\frac1{n^5}$$

and now use Comparison Test plus $\;p$-series test.

Comment: can you please explain the first $\leq$ move?

Comment: @gbox: all the terms in numerator/denominator are positive, so I made numerator greater by taking $\;n^{10}\;$ in each summand there, and made denominator smaller by taking only one summand.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By the [Limit Comparison Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{2n^{10}  + 4 n^5  +1}{4n^{15}  + 4 n^{12}  +5}}{\frac{1}{n^5}}  = \frac{1}{2} > 0$$

Comment: I don't think it's important that the constant is positive. What's important is that it's a $constant$, and hence either both sums diverge, or converge,

Comment: @Alex Well, it is important insofar this test is appliable only to positive series and thus the limit, if it exists, must be non-negative...but if the positiveness is already checked, then indeed the important part is that the limit isn't zero.